# subquery returns more than one row error in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table which contains a list of users and the apps they are allowed to access. Each row in this table has a column for user_id and app_id along with some other stuff, and the presence of such a row is enough for each user to be able to access that app.

I have some users who can access a particular app already, but I would like to see which users don't have access to a particular app and give them access to this app by creating rows in table for each such user.

It would be something like this:

```
SET @v1 := (SELECT user_id from user_app_map WHERE app_id != <app_id_here> );

INSERT INTO user_app_map (user_id, app_id) VALUES (
    (SELECT @v1), <app_id_here> );
```

When I'm executing the above query, I am getting `#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row` error.

I have searched for this error on Google, but the results I got had some problem that was more complicated than this one, so I couldn't understand what I wanted from that.

Please tell me how can I do such an operation?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: I could have done it this way:

```
INSERT INTO user_app_map (user_id, app_id)
  SELECT user_id, <app_id_here> from user_app_map WHERE app_id != <app_id_here>
```

but this method will not work in this case, because some users who have access to multiple apps, have many rows in the table with their id. If I query as said above, I would give the same person access to same app again.

Example: user 3 may have access to app 3 and app 4 both, which means user_app_map contains two rows with user_id 3 and app_id 3 and 4 each. With above query, I get user_id from second row, and again create another row, which would be an unnecessary duplicate of first row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only assign a single value to a variable, so if this query:

```
SELECT user_id from user_app_map WHERE app_id != <app_id_here>
```

returns more than one row (highly likely, unless you only have two rows in your table), you'll get more than one row and thus your exception.

To fix this, either ensure only one row by perhaps using an aggregate function:

```
SET @v1 := (SELECT max(user_id) from user_app_map WHERE app_id != <app_id_here> );
```

Or narrow the rows to one by a tighter where clause.

---

If your intention is to perform the insert for all values, try this:

```
INSERT INTO user_app_map (user_id, app_id) 
SELECT DISTINCT user_id, <app_id_here> from user_app_map WHERE app_id != <app_id_here>
```

Comment: Yeah, it does return multiple rows. How can I do the same without using variable?

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with the last query... Where should the parenthesis after VALUES end?

Comment: ha.. that is the same query CBroe wrote in his answer. Could you please checkout the comments on the other answer. I am not quite getting what I wanted from executing this query, for some reason...

Comment: @ForbiddenOverseer Yes (I should have realised this). Just add `DISTINCT` - see edited query at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a subquery in a place where only one single value is expected - hence this error.

But this can easily be done using [INSERT ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html) syntax, like so:

```
INSERT INTO user_app_map (user_id, app_id)
  SELECT user_id, <app_id_here> from user_app_map WHERE app_id != <app_id_here>
```

The select will select the user_id from the relevant records dynamically, and the second "column" it returns is just a static value.

Comment: Wow... seems like this one just solved my problem!! I thought about writing this query, but doesn't SELECT statement work each time INSERT has been done? Or does it SELECT all records once, and then INSERT them into table? Thanks for the help! Waiting for the reply. :)

Comment: See linked manual page, where it says: _"When selecting from and inserting into a table at the same time, MySQL creates a temporary table to hold the rows from the SELECT and then inserts those rows into the target table. "_

Comment: For some reason, some users didn't get access to apps yet. Does WHERE app_id != <app_id_here> include ones which have app_id set to NULL ?

Comment: Okay, I think there's some problem with this query. In my `user_app_map`, say I have a record which maps user 3 to app 3, and another record which maps user 3 to app 4 - user 3 is still getting selected in this query. I don't want user 3 to be selected at all. How can I do that?

Comment: _"If I query as said above, I would give the same person access to same app again."_ - put a UNIQUE index on the combination user_id+app_id, and then use the IGNORE keyword with your INSERT statement - that way inserted rows that have the same value for user_id/app_id as existing rows will be ignored.